# Jquery UI Modal Dialog Not Working Properly

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, webforms

I created a jQuery modal password dialog box to redirect to a page for password validation.

The modal dialog appears alright, but instead of executing the method that handles the password validation it instead shows the error `[object Object]` on a the browsers alert dialog. I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Below is my code:

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
$(document).on("click", "[id*=lnkView1]", function() {    
    $("#dlgPassword").dialog({
        title: "View Details",
        buttons: {
            Go: function() {
                var valPassword = $("[id*=cpgnPassword]").val();
                var hdfCamId = $('#<%=rptCampaigns.ClientID %>').find('input:hidden[id$="hdfCampaignID"]').val();
                $("[id*=hdfCampaignID2]").val(hdfCamId);
                //var jsonObj = '{password: "' + valPassword + '"}';
                var res;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: '{password: "' + valPassword + '"}',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: 'CampaignsList.aspx/ValidatePasswordWM',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('successful')
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        alert(err.toString());
                    }
                });

                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        modal: true
    });
    return false;
});
```

**Code-Behind**

```
protected void ValidatePassword(object password)
{
    var campaign = new CampaignsService().GetByCampaignId(hdfCampaignID2.Value);
    if (campaign != null)
    { 
        if (campaign.Password.Equals(password))
            Response.Redirect("CampaignDetails.aspx?CampaignID=" + hdfCampaignID2.Value);
    }            
}

[WebMethod]
public static void ValidatePasswordWM(object password)
{
    CampaignsList page = new CampaignsList();
    page.ValidatePassword(password);
}
```

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: use err.responseText instead of err.toString()

Comment: Thanks @Silence. It shows me the exception and the stacktrace. The exception message: `Object reference not set to the instance of an object.` And the stacktrace is on `ValidatePassword` method. I'm guessing the `password` parameter is null. Could that be true?

Comment: you are welcome @kacey one more thing response.redirect not work on web method you can redirect your page client side

Comment: That's why it is not directly on web method but in a separate method which I call under web method

Comment: @KaceyEzerioha I saw you posted about stepping through code in a comment under another answer.  You can step through your JavaScript code in any browser using their Developer Tools.  In most browsers, hitting F12 will open the development tools where there is a built in debugger.

Comment: @KaceyEzerioha Can you post the actual error messages you're recieving in full (including their stack trace if they exist) as well as where the issue is.  It's unclear if this is a server-side issue or client-side issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `appendTo` property on your dialog so it gets added to the form properly.

```
$("#dlgPassword").dialog({
    title: "View Details",
    appendTo: "form",
    buttons: {
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Mason. I added that. But it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `err.toString()`, try `err.message`

Comment: Thanks for your response Johnie. I changed it just as instructed. Now I see `Undefined`. I wish I could step through the code to know what is going on. But I have no idea how to step through jquery.

Answer (score 0):

This code shows a products cadastre at jQuery UI. When OK button pressed, re-populate dropdownlist.

Javascript:

```
$dialog = $("#dlgCadastroProduto").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 500,
    width: 700,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");                
            $("#lstProducts").empty();
            $("#lstSelectedProducts").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/Produto/jsonLoad',
                async: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                success:
                    function (data) {
                      //alert('sucesso');
                      $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                          //insere elemento na droplist
                        $("#lstProducts").append('<option value='+value.ID+'>'+value.Descricao+'</option>')                    
                      });
                    },
                error: function (data) {
                     //alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

$("#btnCadastroProduto").button().on("click", function () {
    $dialog.dialog("open");
});
```

Code-Behind at Controller:

```
    public JsonResult jsonLoad()
    {
        var lista = _produtoBLL.FindAll();
        var xpto = lista.Select(x => new { Id = x.ID, Descricao = x.Descricao });
        return Json(xpto, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I hope i have helped

Answer (score 0):

This is just sample code you can you with yours

**Client Side**

```
var mparam = "{param1:'" + mvar1 + "',param_n:'" + mvar_n + "'}";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "file_name.aspx/web_method",
    data: mparam,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (Response) {
        try {
            var msdata = JSON.parse(Response.d);
            if (msdata.err == "0") {
                location.replace("newlocation");
            }else{
                alert("Error:" + msdata.msg);
            }           
        } catch (e) {
            alert("Error in JSON parser error:" + e.description);
        }
    },
    error: function (medata) {
        alert("Internal Server Error:" + medata);
    }
});
```

**Server Side**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string web_method(string param1, string param_n)
{
    string strerror = "0", strmessage = "";
    try
    {
        strerror = "0";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        strerror = "2";
        strmessage = ex.Message;
    }

    return "{\"err\":\"" + strerror + "\",\"msg\":\"" + strmessage + "\"}";
}
```

Comment: Be very careful using `try...catch` in JavaScript, as it's not used very often, and support for it is a bit finicky across different engines.  Additionally, it's slow & doesn't work very well with async operations.  There's a pretty good discussion over at [programmers.se](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/144326/try-catch-in-javascript-isnt-it-a-good-practice) on the topic, as well as lots of articles that say you should probably avoid it in *most* situations.  That being said there are certainly uses for it, but I don't believe this is one of them.

Comment: Also, try to explain why your code fixes the issues in your answers instead of just providing sample code.